# Move system with encrypted homedir to another drive

Tags: linux, hard-drive, debian, ssd, encryption

I'm on debian (squeeze) and I have my user homedir (/home/storm, 20GB) encrypted with cryptsetup. My goal is to safely migrate from 80gb hdd to a new 60gb ssd. As you can see the target disk is of smaller size, so simply dd'ing won't do it.

Any advice of what is the best way to move the whole system? Thanks!

Here's how things look:

```
# df -h
    Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    /dev/sda3             9,2G  2,1G  6,7G  24% /
    tmpfs                 1,6G     0  1,6G   0% /lib/init/rw
    udev                  1,6G  180K  1,6G   1% /dev
    tmpfs                 1,6G  1,5M  1,6G   1% /dev/shm
    /dev/sda1              61G   22G   36G  38% /home
    /dev/mapper/home       19G  1,3G   17G   8% /home/storm

# fdisk -l /dev/sda
    Disk /dev/sda: 80.0 GB, 80025280000 bytes
       Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
    /dev/sda1            1704        9730    64467968   83  Linux
    /dev/sda2               2         488     3905536   82  Linux swap / Solaris
    Partition 2 does not end on cylinder boundary.
    /dev/sda3   *         488        1704     9765888   83  Linux
```

I believe suitable approach would be to partition the new disk pretty much the same as the old one, just making /home (/dev/sda1) 20Gs less = 41G, and then just rsync the data to corresponding folders and finally chroot into the newly copied folder and install grub to the new disk, am I right? If yes, then what keys to rsync should I use when copying / filesystem? (I believe I'd need to skip /dev, maybe /proc and so on, not really sure)

Comment: Adjust the size of the partitions then use the cloning tool of your choice

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41091/how-can-i-shrink-a-luks-partition-what-does-cryptsetup-resize-do) for an exchange on shrinking a LUKS partition.  The key being to shrink the filesystem then run cryptsetup resize to shrink it.

Alternatively, why not simply create a new LUKS partition on the new drive, mount both, then copy the data (unencrypted) between the drives - then fiddle around with the boot process to make it decrypt the new drive ?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I edited my initial question adding some details. I really don't know if your suggestion on shrinking LUKS partition is relevant though, it's only 20G.